# How can I remove button and key events in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to remove the Bold button form my CKEditor. I used the below-mentioned code. but it's only removing the icon from the toolbar. I want to remove key events also. when I press ctrl+b it's put  tag in the backend.

http://ckeditor.com/comment/123266#comment-123266

Comment: trysomething like this $("a[title='Bold (Ctrl+B)']").remove()  ...execute it after the ckeditor is loaded ..

Comment: can we have any default functionality like remove button?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting command **Bold** is part of [basicstyles](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/basicstyles) plugin and removing this plugin, would remove all other formatting commands. So, you should use configuration option [removeButtons](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-removeButtons) to remove just this one.

```
config.removeButtons = 'Bold';
```

Comment: I already this. it's not working means it' removes only button

Comment: With the above command, bold formatting command is removed completely, ctrl+b is not available, tested it with v4.12.1

Comment: I am using CKEditor 4.6.1 here. it's not working. I want to know whether it's a CKEditor problem or mine?

Comment: Load CKEditor from CDN https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ and remove the bold button, then see if it works.